# How to keep state inside a ruby module?

Tags: ruby, module, scope

Here is an example module that behaves kind of like a hash:

```
module Hashlike
  def store key, value
    (@hash ||= {})[key] = value
  end

  def retrieve key
    (@hash ||= {})[key]
  end
end
```

And a class that includes it:

```
class MyHash
  include Hashlike
end
```

Now this works well and I can store and retrieve from an instance:

```
> my_hash = MyHash.new
=> #<MyHash:0xc1808d8>
> my_hash.store :a, 1
=> 1
> my_hash.retrieve :a
=> 1
```

Unfortunately, the instance now has an instance variable `@hash` coming from the module. This could have collided with existing instance variables:

```
> my_hash.instance_variable_get '@hash'
=> {:a=>1}
```

What's the best way to restrict the scope of instance variables defined in modules to not clutter the scope of the instances including these modules?

In other words, where should modules keep their state?

Comment: Normally such variables are "namespaced" within the module, e.g., `@_hashlike_hash` etc. to reduce, while not *100%* eliminating the change of a problem. You could probably generate a name somehow.

Comment: @DaveNewton: UUID to the rescue? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev My hesitation was with the relative worth, not the technique ;)

Comment: @Matt Why not subclass Hash instead?

Comment: Modules aren't use for holding state, only behaviour. Why not create a Class instead?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I understand I could create a class, but I am interested in the more general question of keeping state cleanly in a module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply rename the instance variable to reduce chances of collision.

```
module Hashlike
  def store(key, value)
    _hash[key] = value
  end

  def retrieve(key)
    _hash[key]
  end

  private
  def _hash
    @_hashlike_storage ||= {}
  end
end

class MyHash
  include Hashlike
end

my_hash = MyHash.new
my_hash.store :a, 1 # => 1
my_hash.retrieve :a # => 1
my_hash.instance_variables # => [:@_hashlike_storage]
```